Periodic Voltage and Current Fluctuations in Autonomous Robot System
I have an autonomous robot system powered by a 24V LiFePO4 battery that has several distributed PCBA's getting their power from the 24V battery, and also having their own on-board DC-DC buck converters for powering local components. The main chassis of the robot is connected to BATT(-), however there are some metal parts underneath the robot which are isolated from the BATT(-). The grounds of all the regulators are also tied back to BATT(-). High level system diagram:

The crux of what I'm seeing is that repeatably (can be replicated every couple of minutes), every time the robot is in motion (doesn't occur at standstill), a quick but large current and voltage event can be seen not only on the main +24V signal, but also on the regulated output of the DC-DC converters. See image below:

Yellow waveform = +24V measured near the battery;
Light blue waveform = 24V -> 12V -> 5V regulated output on one of the boards;
Dark blue waveform = +24V battery current.
These fluctuations can be seen even when powering off almost all of the system (including large motors, etc.), and only physically moving the robot by disengaging the brakes.
Question is: Has anyone seen this type of phenomenon before, or can correlate these types of fluctuations to any known root cause?
It has been difficult debugging and identifying a true root cause and am looking for any insight as to what could be happening. Lots of investigation has been done which I can elaborate on more if necessary, but the following areas have been considered:

ESD
Power switching noise
Back EMF (from the brake coil)


Where is your oscilloscope ground, also please provide a block diagram of the system.

Disabling the motors was a good start. I recommend you keep disconnecting things and testing until you narrow it down. Imo, if you can reproduce it, you can fix it.

I would expect the battery rail to be noisy on a robot, so your PCBs should be designed to handle that, but this does look like way more than normal.

The wheels can build up a large static charge, that arcs if the voltage is high enough. The battery current probably does not fluctuate that much, just the probes pick up the ESD discharge pulse everywhere.

@VoltageSpike - Oscilloscope ground is connected to BATT- (near the battery itself for the yellow waveform measurement), and near the respective board for the light blue waveform measurement. Unfortunately, I can't provide a complete block diagram of the system, but I'll add a basic one for increased clarity.

@Drew - Thanks for your suggestions. I'm essentially able to reproduce it at this point by driving the robot around for a couple of minutes and triggering on any fluctuations. Just trying to deduce root cause now.

@Jens - This was the leading theory so far for me, ESD build up on the drive wheels that's arcing perhaps onto the chassis which allows it to make its way back to the battery, disturbing the voltage rails in the system. Do you think that these fluctuations could be more of an artifact of the probing, and not be present at the actual devices?

If you measure only one DC-DC converter's output, connecting the scope probe center and ground right at its output terminals, do you still see these fluctuations?

I assume this noise is radiated. Can you see this on the scope if you only connect a 20 cm wire loop to the probe @ 100 mV/div and put it between the boards?

@SimonFitch - Yes, some fluctuations are still present even when only measuring one DC-DC converter output (the 5V output in this case), with very short leads to the output terminals (+/- 1.5V or so can be seen). They don't seem to be as pronounced in magnitude as the screenshot in my original post.
